# How to combine strings from NSMutable array

Tags: ios5, nsstring, xcode4.2, string-concatenation

I'm trying to figure out how to combine the data from an NSMutable array to be part of an email body.  The following code produces the following NSLog output:

```
- (void)emailBody
{
    NSLog(@"Number of Songs: %@", profile.profileNumberOfSongs);
    NSLog(@"Profile Length:  %@", [self convertSecondstoMMSS:[profile.profileDuration intValue]]);

    for (ProfileItems *item in profileItemsNSMArray) 
    {
        NSLog(@"%@ %@ - %@ %@", item.profileItemsSongOrder, item.profileItemsMovementName, item.profileItemsArtist, item.profileItemsSong);
    }
}
```

NSLog output:

```
 Number of Songs: 9
 Profile Length:  40:07
 1 Seated Flat - Foo Fighters Home
 2 Seated Flat - Foo Fighters What If I Do?
 3 Standing Climb - Foo Fighters Tired Of You
```

What is the best way to store this data into a single NSString to be passed to be the body of an email?

Thanks in advance

-Paul

Answer (score 0):

```
- (NSString *)emailBody
{
    NSMutableString *emailBodyString = [NSMutableString string];
    [emailBodyString appendFormat:@"Number of Songs: %@", profile.profileNumberOfSongs];
    [emailBodyString appendFormat:@"Profile Length: %@", [self convertSecondstoMMSS:[profile.profileDuration intValue]]];

    for (ProfileItems *item in profileItemsNSMArray) 
    {
        [emailBodyString appendFormat:@"%@ %@ - %@ %@", item.profileItemsSongOrder, item.profileItemsMovementName, item.profileItemsArtist, item.profileItemsSong];
    }

    return emailBodyString;
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the speedy response.

Comment: Shows the answer was accepted then unaccepted. Did it not work?